# MySQL query to calculate percentage within each group

Tags: mysql, sql

How to convert this result:

```
week,day,hour,branch,sales
1,1,1,a,50
1,1,1,b,50
1,1,2,a,25
1,1,2,b,75
```

Into this:

```
week,day,hour,branch,sales,percentage
1,1,1,a,50,50%
1,1,1,b,50,50%
1,1,2,a,25,25%
1,1,2,b,75,75%
```

Note that the percentage is grouped by each hour. In other words, it is not the percentage of all the sales but just the sales within each hour. I have tried the following query but this gives me percentage of all the sales:

```
SELECT week,day,hour,branch,sales,
(sales/(SELECT SUM(sales) FROM test))*100 AS Percentage
FROM test
GROUP BY week,day,hour,branch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT week, day, hour, branch, sales,
       (sales/(SELECT SUM(sales)
               FROM test t2
               WHERE t2.hour = t.hour and t2.week = t.week and t2.day = t.day
              )
       ) * 100 AS Percentage
FROM test t
GROUP BY week, day, hour, branch;
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Gordon.

Comment: While this query works, it becomes really slow on large tables. I tried it on a table with around 120000 rows and after 20 minutes I am still waiting for the result. I was wondering if there is a way to optimise this for large tables?

Comment: @Adnan . . . Try adding an index on `test(week, day, hour, sales)` and see if that helps.